# Override backend url from CLI for proxy to Host machine

Tags: traefik

Is possible to override backend URL for file provider from CLI?

For example:

```
docker rm -f traefik-cockpit; docker run -d  -p 443:443 \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
--label 'traefik.enable=true' \
--label 'traefik.file.backend.url=127.0.0.1' \
--label 'traefik.docker.network=host' \
--label 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:cockpit.myexample.com' \
--label 'traefik.port=9090' \
--label 'traefik.protocol=http' \
--name traefik-cockpit \
traefik:v1.6.6-alpine \
--file \
--defaultentrypoints="https" \
--entryPoints='Name:https Address::443 TLS' \
--docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock \
--docker.exposedbydefault=false \
--docker.watch=true
```

There are a lot of applications which are running on Host directly, this will enable autoconfig for File provider from CLI

Possible solutions:

```
--label 'traefik.file.backend.url=127.0.0.1' \
--label 'traefik.docker.network=host' \
```

or

```
--label 'traefik.file.backend.url=192.168.0.5' \
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that:

- labels are for the static configuration
- backends and frontends are in the dynamic configuration

https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#configuration